# Running aws S3 locally to test saving of images

Tags: amazon-s3

Hi everyone we implemented aws S3 for uploading images and generating pdfs through this images. However on our local testing server we cannot use the aws S3 locally and I am looking for ways to run aws S3 locally maybe using docker or another software.

Do you have any recommendations?

EDIT: I use docker for the local DB and Tomcat for the local server

Comment: Or: [GitHub - localstack: A fully functional local AWS cloud stack. Develop and test your cloud & Serverless apps offline!](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT run S3 locally.

What you can do is to mimic the S3 API calls.

see https://github.com/spulec/moto
https://medium.com/@l.peppoloni/how-to-mock-s3-services-in-python-tests-dd5851842946